# Matplotlib: TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following jpeg as a bytecode string:

```
jpg = 'b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x01\x00`\x00`\x00\x00\xff\xfe\x00>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v80), default quality\n\xff\xdb\x00C\x00\x08\x06\x06\x07
```

I want to dispaly this for image processing with openCV.

I tried:

```
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    nparr = np.fromstring(jpg, np.uint8)

    plt.imshow(nparr, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
```

I'm getting:

```
 File "....\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3205, in imshow
    **kwargs)
  File "....\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1855, in inner
    return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)
  File "....\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5487, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "....\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 653, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Invalid dimensions for image data")
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

How can I get this working?